# What's the benefit of using docker for websphere liberty?

Tags: docker, websphere-liberty, open-liberty

As Liberty has already added a server package function, it's easy enough to package a server from development to production. So why do I still need docker? Does it give any advantage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a vibrant ecosystem around orchestrating and managing containers. If you're unzipping packaged servers to deploy them, you're going to be left in the cold to develop your own solutions (or go without them) for all of the investment/advancements being done in a way that affects pretty much anything in a container.  For example, scaling, failover, injecting faults, blue/green deployments, service discovery, metrics, security ...

If you can get your application into a container, you can be sure it will interoperate with any contemporary infrastructure and almost immediately be able to take advantages of all the bells and whistles.